# Vertices that seems to be aligned, are not?

Tags: 3d-printing

Hi all and good to be here. 
I'm new to the forum and fairly new to Blender. I did some tutorials and simple drawings, but now I want to 3D print my designs.

I've created a rim (1/24 meant to be used in scale modeling) 
The inside of the rim containts a 'cylinder' that will be used to attach the wheel to the model car. For some reason, the vertices shown in the image below appear to be somewhat offset when I slice the STL export for printing. However, all the vertices have the same Z value of -11mm.
What am I missing/doing wrong?

[image: Rear view of the rim]

According to the slicing tool the outer rim first appears on the third layer, where the center starts on the 1st.
[image: Slicing tool for the Anycubic Photon printer]

I am aware this could also be a problem from the slicing software... but let's look at the design first.

Comment: Have you tried selecting all of the vertices and changing the Z value again? maybe there's some missing

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. That was when I made the screenshot ;) Perhaps I will cut off the highlighted section and redo the extrusion, but this time for both the outer and the inner parts at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. 
In my scene collection I still had the original cylinder I used to create the center part. I'd set it to invisible, but when exporting this object was 'actived' and visibly added to the stl file. 
Jep that feels like a newbee mistake :S

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i had problems like that as well. I ended up just starting from new and being very careful. Blender sometimes just creates some weird slightly invisible vertecies out if nothing. and if u don't ctrl + z them, I don't find any way to get rid of them